# How to make git to clone svn settings also?

Tags: git, configuration, git-svn

I'd like to create a read-only Git mirror of a SVN repository. I don't need to setup the Git->SVN direction and I've already done the SVN-Git synchronization.

Now I would like to somehow "clone" the git-svn setup from the Git server to a local Git repository as I would like to have a possibility to commit to the SVN repository directly, not via the Git mirror. For instance, after cloning my Git repository with `git pull` and committing some changes, I'd like to do `git svn dcommit` and the commit should be correctly written to the SVN repository. I don't need to fetch the changes directly from SVN, though it'd be nice to have such possibility. Obviously, I don't want to clone the SVN repository (which has about 45.000 revisions) from scratch to my local disc.

Is this somehow possible or is there any easy script that would solve my problem? Or is there any better way to solve the whole Git mirroring? Unfortunately, I don't have admin access to the SVN repository.

Comment: That is not easily possible. Have you tried cloning and then pulling from the svn repo? Git-svn might reuse the history that is already there.

Comment: Yep, but git svn fetch starts to clone the whole history again.